# What visa is needed for Indian child of a Filipina mother to visit the Philippines?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, filipino-citizens, philippines

My baby is an Indian national and my wife is a Filipina. What is the process needed for my baby to enter the Philippines as a visitor?

Comment: My baby is on visit visa to Saudi Arabia

Answer (score 2):

Your child is a Filipino citizen.

As such your wife needs to report their birth with the Philippine embassy and get them a Philippine passport.

Comment: Getting the child a Philippine passport will cause the child to lose Indian citizenship, so it won't be a feasible course of action for many people in this circumstance.

Comment: @phoog Indian minors can be dual citizens, but have to make a choice within 6 months of turning 18.

Comment: They can be dual citizens, but not if they get a passport from their other country of citizenship. That is considered under Indian law to constitute voluntary acquisition of another nationality, even though that logically isn't true, and therefore results in the loss of Indian nationality.  See http://www.lawsindia.com/Advocate%20Library/Amendments/citizen_ship_rules/MAIN.htm.

Comment: @phoog How would Indian authorities know the baby got a Philippine passport?

Comment: By wondering how the child got into the Philippines without a visa in the Indian passport.

Comment: @phoog How do they know the child has been to the Philippines at all? There are no direct flights Philippines-India AFAIK, and the child does have a Saudi visa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77336/discussion-between-phoog-and-coke).